# How to overload a function with variable arguments

Tags: typescript, angular-pipe

I currently have a translation pipe that takes variable arguments

```
@Pipe({name: 'translate', pure: true})
export class TranslationPipe {
    constructor(private service: TranslationService) {}
    transform(key: string, ...params: (number|string)[]): string {
        // The translation service takes an array
        return this._service.translate(key, params);
    }
}
```

For a message like `error.message=You have {0} of {1} tries left`, it's called like the following in a template

```
{{ 'error.message' | translate : currentTry : totalTriesAllowed }}
```

However, we now have a case where a component takes the key and the replacements parameters as an array (because it doesn't know how many there could be since the key is provided by the caller) and I don't know of a good way to create an overload for that method.

I did try to spread the arguments from the template but that is not valid syntax

```
{{ translationKey | translate : ...translationArgs }}
```

To be able to make this work, I thought I'd need an overload like the following so that the translation pipe can also pass an array as the first argument instead of separate arguments

```
transform(key: string, params: (string|number)[]): string;
transform(key: string, ...params: (string|number)[]): string;
```

However, I haven't been able to find a good implementation for supporting this overload. This is where I am currently.

```
type ArryayOfStringOrNumber  = (string|number)[];
export class TranslationPipe {
    // ERROR: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation
    transform(key: string, params: ArryayOfStringOrNumber): string;
    transform(key: string, ...params: ArryayOfStringOrNumber): string;
    transform(key: string, ...params: ArryayOfStringOrNumber): any {
        if (params[0] instanceof Array) {
            // ERROR: The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must 
            //        be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.
            params = params[0] as ArryayOfStringOrNumber;
        }
        return this._service.translate(key, params as ArryayOfStringOrNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not keep your code as-is and instead pass the array to the rest parameter by using spread syntax? `pipe.transform(key, ...args);`

Comment: @DavidSherret The question is in regards to being able to call such function from a template. `{{ translationKey | translate : ...translationArgs }}` doesn't work. I'm not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question in detail so I didn't notice it was about angular. No wonder I was confused about the `{{ ... }}` syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function implementing the overload has to accept an array of objects where each could be of type `(string|number)[]` or an array of those, that is `((string|number)[])[]`

```
transform(key: string, ...params: (ArryayOfStringOrNumber|(string|number))[]): any {
    if (params[0] instanceof Array) {
        params = params[0] as ArryayOfStringOrNumber;
    }
    return this._service.translate(key, params as ArryayOfStringOrNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem and what I did was split the first possible argument of the spread array, make it a union type and prepend it to the spread array if necessary.

The result was kinda like this:

```
foo(bar: Bar): void;
foo(...bazs: Array<Baz>): void;
foo(barOrBaz: Bar | Baz, ...bazsRest: Array<Baz>): void {
    if (barOrBaz instanceof Bar) {
        let bar = barOrBaz;
        // first overload
    } else {
        let bazs = [barOrBaz, ...bazsRest];
        // second overload
    }
}
```

So in your case the implementation could also be written like this:

```
transform(key: string, paramsFirst: string | number | ArrayOfStringOrNumber, ...paramsRest: ArrayOfStringOrNumber): string {
    let params = paramsFirst instanceof Array ? paramsFirst : [paramsFirst, ...paramsRest];
    return this._service.translate(key, params);
}
```